# Not able to preserve bytes values>127 with ReadExisting();

Tags: visual-c++

I read bytes from a microcontroller in VC++2010(that i dont know absolutely but i must use as in lack of someone else) using SerialPort and on DataReceived event.

```
private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, 
System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e) 
        {


String^mystr;
mystr = serialPort1->ReadExisting();
```

I need raw data but everything >0x7F looks changed to 0x3F.
in the watch window mystr[3]=0x3F,despite i sent 0x80;
Why are some data lost?I expect that a raw byte could be converted in a char ,maybe an impossible to print char,but without altering the data.
Is there any way to have an array of raw data instead?
Thanks

Comment: Why not use a byte array instead of a string?

Comment: Thanks for your answer
i dont know how to declare a byte array in this environment,by now the only type that does not produce errors in my project is the type String^.
Please can you type an example?
Thanks